# To check diagonalizability of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> **True / false :** There exists a $5 \times5$ real matrix $A$ which is diagonalizable, but $A^5 - 7A^4 + 5A^2 + 2I$ is not diagonalizable.

I tried to solve this problem by taking matrix A such that at least two of its eigen values are distinct real roots of the polynomial $x^5 - 7x^4 + 5x^2 +2$, so that i get the corresponding eigen values of $A^5 - 7A^4 + 5A^2 +2I$, zero two times to prove that it is not diagonalizable. I kow that this polynomial has atleast one real root, but i am not sure if i can find another distinct real root. How can I proceed?
Or is there any other method to know if the statement is true or false?

Comment: Hint: how are the eigenVECTORS of $A^2$ related to the eigenvectors of $A$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A=P^{-1}DP$,

then \begin{align}
A^5-7A^4+5A^2+2I &= (P^{-1}DP)^5 - 7(P^{-1}DP)^4+5(P^{-1}DP)^2+2(P^{-1}IP) \\
&=(P^{-1}D^5P) - 7(P^{-1}D^4P)+5(P^{-1}D^2P)+2(P^{-1}IP) \\
&=P^{-1}(D^5 - 7D^4+5D^2+2I)P \\
\end{align}

Comment: I would take D as a diagonal matrix. Is it true that if D has 5 linearly independent eigen vectors then D^5 - 7D^4 + 5D^2 - D + 2I, also has 5 linearly independent eigen vectors?If yes, then clearly the statement is false.

Comment: the statement is false.